# SELECT favorites from mysql and displaying them?

Tags: php, mysql

I've set up a basic favorite script in php which stores a users favorite users.

So user-a can favorite user-b and vice versa.

Here's my code for that so far:

```
<a href="favorite.php?to=<?php echo $profile_id; ?>">+ Favorite</a>
```

.

```
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');
include 'includes/_config/connection.php';

session_start();


    confirm_logged_in();




    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_favorites (user_id, favorite_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")") 
or die(mysql_error());
echo 'Done.';

?>
```

Now i just want to eho out the results of each users own favorites?
I've tried this but it won't echo out anything?

```
function get_favorites() {
            global $connection;
            global $profile_id;
            $query = "SELECT f.user_id, f.favorite_id, p.user_id, p.display_name
                        FROM ptb_favorites f, ptb_profiles p
                        WHERE f.favorite_id = \"$profile_id\"
                        AND f.user_id =".$_SESSION['user_id']."";
            $get_favorites_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($query, $connection);
            return $get_favorites_set;

            }

    <?php
            $get_favorites_set = get_favorites();
            while ($favorites = mysql_fetch_array($get_favorites_set)) {

    ?>

    <div class="reviewcase" id="reviewcase">
                 <div class="forum-content">
                 <?php echo "{$favorites['display_name']}"; ?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="message_pic">
                 <?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id={$favorites['favorite_id']}\"><img width=\"50px\" height=\"50px\"  src=\"{$prof_photo}\"></a>";?>
                 </div>

                 <? } ?>
```

I'm still learning php and mysql so could someone explain where i'm going wrong and what i need to do to successfully get this results displayed. Thanks.

Comment: just a general practice, allways put `session_start()` as the first line of code

Comment: The mysql_* functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and be a [better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: please let us know what exactly the problem is, what output are you getting or waht errors you are encountering, as a start it seems your function get_favourites() is NOT in a php tag space, i would also suggest you pass the profile id as a varibale to the function isntead of using globals

Comment: why are you loading `includes/_config/connection.php` twice?

Answer (score 0):

What is this? `<?php echo "{$favorites['display_name']}"; ?>` it should be `echo $favorites['display_name'];` It's faster.

Also, try using a `foreach` loop instead of a `while` loop near the end.